# MySQL multiple rows with same id meeting two different conditions at same time

Tags: mysql

I am using OTRS helpdesk ticket management system. When i execute following Query:

```
SELECT  `ticket`.`id`,  
`ticket_history`.`ticket_id`,  
`ticket_history`.`id`,
`ticket_history`.`name`,  
`ticket_history`.`create_time` 
FROM  `ticket_history` 
INNER JOIN  `ticket` ON  `ticket_history`.`ticket_id` =  `ticket`.`id` 
WHERE  `ticket_history`.`name` LIKE  '%Raw% %new%'
OR  `ticket_history`.`name` LIKE  '%Close'
ORDER BY  `ticket_history`.`ticket_id`, `ticket_history`.`id` ASC
```

I get the following output:

```
+----+-----------+-----+-------------------------------------------+---------------------+
| id | ticket_id | id  |                   name                    |     create_time     |
+----+-----------+-----+-------------------------------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |         1 |  79 | %%Close                                   | 2013-06-10 11:50:33 |
|  2 |         2 |   2 | %%2013060810000011%%Raw%%3 normal%%new%%2 | 2013-06-08 21:59:02 |
|  3 |         3 |   5 | %%2013060810000021%%Raw%%3 normal%%new%%3 | 2013-06-08 21:59:03 |
|  3 |         3 |  22 | %%Close                                   | 2013-06-08 22:10:41 |
|  3 |         3 |  82 | %%Close                                   | 2013-06-10 11:50:49 |
|  4 |         4 |  88 | %%Close                                   | 2013-06-10 11:51:32 |
|  5 |         5 |  64 | %%2013060910000019%%Raw%%3 normal%%new%%5 | 2013-06-09 17:12:09 |
|  5 |         5 |  85 | %%Close                                   | 2013-06-10 11:51:10 |
|  6 |         6 |  92 | %%2013061010000016%%Raw%%3 normal%%new%%6 | 2013-06-10 12:00:24 |
|  7 |         7 |  95 | %%2013061010000025%%Raw%%3 normal%%new%%7 | 2013-06-10 13:05:05 |
|  8 |         8 |  98 | %%2013061110000014%%Raw%%3 normal%%new%%8 | 2013-06-11 19:05:06 |
|  8 |         8 | 109 | %%Close                                   | 2013-06-17 23:57:35 |
|  9 |         9 | 163 | %%2013061810000011%%Raw%%3 normal%%new%%9 | 2013-06-18 02:05:06 |
+----+-----------+-----+-------------------------------------------+---------------------+
```

I need to modify the above query so I can only list rows of each ticket_id which has "%RAW% %new%" in name and at the same time same ticket_id has a row which has "%Close" in it.

In other words, Three rows of ticket_id 3, Two rows of ticket_id 5 and Two Rows of ticket_id 8 should be displayed from the above output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't going to be a query that scales very well, no matter which approach you take, since text matching anywhere in a column except at the left edge of an indexed column will require a full table scan.

I'm not familiar with OTRS ... I downloaded it and looked at the source scripts that create the database schema and it looks like the column you're querying is the result of denormalization and they're using the %% symbols to do language localization... so querying the way you're doing it is not likely to be, as some people like to say, very "performant."

Bear in mind also that `%` is a wildcard character for the [MySQL `LIKE` operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-comparison-functions.html), so what you're actually matching on, as written, could lead to false positives, because your expression is evaluated by MySQL as trying to match `*raw*[space]*new*` and `*close`.

What you appear to be actually searching for is `%\%Raw\%% %\%new\%%` where `%` means anything and `\%` means a literal `%`, not a wildcard.  Also, you want `%\%Close`, or possibly `%\%Close%` if the '%Close' can be found anywhere other than at the end of a line.

Importantly, I suspect there is a better way to get the data you are looking for from OTRS, so you should review the schema and consider whether this is a possibility.  For example, if you are looking for tickets that have been closed, it looks like to me that this might be tickets `WHERE` ticket.ticket_state_id = 2 or possibly tickets `WHERE` ticket_history.state_id = 2?  Similarly, wouldn't a ticket with ticket_history.queue_id = 2 mean "Raw"?

Those literal "2" values may not be correct, depending on your version and precisely how OTRS uses its database, but understanding the schema and querying the database in a more optimizer-friendly fashion will get you a substantially better-performing query than searching every row of the table with `LIKE`.

As your query is written, and also in the example below, every row of the ticket_history table will have to be scanned at least once, no matter what you do.

So I would not begin to suggest that the following is "the right way to do it" but it adds in the logic your query is missing.  If a row contains one pattern, we verify whether the ticket_history contains a row for the same ticket that matches the other pattern, and if so, we keep that row ... and if not, we discard it.

```
SELECT `ticket`.`id`,  
       `th`.`ticket_id`,  
       `th`.`id`,
       `th`.`name`,  
       `th`.`create_time` 
  FROM `ticket_history` th
  JOIN `ticket` ON  `th`.`ticket_id` =  `ticket`.`id` 
 WHERE (
        `th`.`name` LIKE  '%\%Raw\%% %\%new\%%'
        AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ticket_history th1 WHERE th1.ticket_id = th.id AND th1.name LIKE '%\%Close')
       )
    OR (
        `th`.`name` LIKE  '%\%Close'
        AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ticket_history th2 WHERE th2.ticket_id = th.id AND th2.name LIKE '%\%Raw\%% %\%new\%%')
       )
 ORDER BY `ticket_history`.`ticket_id`, `ticket_history`.`id` ASC;
```